# CSS background image not showing on my computer

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to use a local image as the background image for part of my website. However, after I have entered the URL of the image and run the project, nothing shows up. Could some please help me out. I am new to CSS and HTML. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Code for HTML file:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <h1 class="logo">JN</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#youtube">YouTube</a></li>
                <li><a href="#articles">Articles</a></li>
                <li><a href="#vine">Vine</a></li>
                <li><a href="#social">Social</a></li>
                <li><a href="#podcasts">Podcasts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#share">Share</a></li>
                <li><a href="#more">More</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a href="mailto:thismailisforrandomstuffs@gmail.com">Email me</a>
    </header>
</body>
```

Code for CSS file:

```
h1.logo {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-image: url(JN-website-logo-Transparent-background.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Path for CSS file on my computer is:

`/Users/justin/Desktop/JN website/JN/public_html/CssAbout.css`

Path for the image on my computer is:

`/Users/justin/Desktop/JN website/JN/Image/JN-website-logo-Transparent-background.svg`

Answer (score 1):

remove visibility:hidden

```
h1.logo {
 background-image: url(JN-website-logo-Transparent-background.svg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: The reason why I wrote visibility:hidden is becasue the image I'm adding is a logo, so I want the text "JN" from <h1 class="logo">JN</h1> to be hidden. Do you know if there is anyway I can hide the text but show the background image? Thanks

Comment: Just remove 'JN' from the `h1` tag? Like: `<h1 class="logo"></h1>`

Comment: If I remove the JN, the logo disappear again. Any idea why? Sorry for all the troubles.

Comment: which browser you are using

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `visibility: hidden;` statement

Or change it  to `visibility: visible;`

Comment: I think it might be better to completely remove this line.

Answer (score 0):

There are two remarkable lines in your CSS:

1. `visibility: hidden;`

Well I think that this line speaks for itself. It causes `h1` to be invisible. You can safely remove this line.

2. `background-image: url(JN-website-logo-Transparent-background.svg);`

For this line we have to take a look at the following:

> Path for CSS file on my computer is:
>
> /Users/justin/Desktop/JN website/JN/public_html/CssAbout.css
>
> Path for the image on my computer is:
>
> /Users/justin/Desktop/JN
>   website/JN/Image/JN-website-logo-Transparent-background.svg

You've set the background-image to a file `JN-website-logo-Transparent-background.svg`. But this file is not in the same folder as your CSS file.
You'll have to change that line to: `background-image: url('...');` where the dots have to be replaced with your image file path.

Comment: Note: it might be wise to move the entire `image` folder to `public_html`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding size to h1

```css
h1.logo {
  background-image: url(http://domaingang.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/example.png);
  //your image
  //background-image: url(JN-website-logo-Transparent-background.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <h1 class="logo"></h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#youtube">YouTube</a></li>
                <li><a href="#articles">Articles</a></li>
                <li><a href="#vine">Vine</a></li>
                <li><a href="#social">Social</a></li>
                <li><a href="#podcasts">Podcasts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#share">Share</a></li>
                <li><a href="#more">More</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a href="mailto:thismailisforrandomstuffs@gmail.com">Email me</a>
    </header>
</body>
```

let me know if the image appear now.

Answer (score 0):

```
h1.logo {
 background-image: url(JN-website-logo-Transparent-background.svg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: contain;

 font-size: 0px;
 line-height: 20px;
}
```

The font size and line-height properties should make the text inside your `h1` invisible without hiding the background-image. The line-height specifically is what prevents the `h1` from shrinking down too much.

Answer (score 0):

You mention

> ...after I have entered the URL of the image and run the project

This suggests that your webpage is running on a local http test server, which means that the server uses a domain or alias for your website(for example: **localhost/JN website** or **192.168.xxx.xxx/JN website**).

The server puts this in front of the filename (as in **http://localhost**/Users/justin/Desktop/JN website/JN/Image/JN-website-logo-Transparent-background.svg) which does not exist. Try changing the CSS to `background: url(../Image/JN-website-logo-Transparent-background.svg)` this is a relative path to the image and should be found by the server (as in **localhost/Image/JN-website-logo-Transparent-background.svg**).

And, of course, remove `h1 {visibility: hidden}`